# Blackberry: trackwheel stop motion listener

Tags: java, blackberry, dictionary, listener, trackball

I'm implementing an app that has a `MapField`, which I am extending.

I'm using `navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time)` to move around this map (besides `touchEvent(TouchEvent event)` which i dont have a problem with).

The problem is that I want to do something when the user stops moving using the `trackwheel`, but I can't find a `listener` for this like the `TouchEvent.UP` for example.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can use to detect this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not (yet) that familiar with BlackBerry-programming, but I don't remember seeing a listener for that anywhere.

One way I could think of to accomplish this could be to create a [TimerTask](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/TimerTask.html), and store a timestamp in some class-variable when the TrackWheel moves (when your navigationMovement is called). Then in the navigationMovement, set the timestamp when the movement occurred (from the time-parameter passed to the method), and start a TimerTask which would then check after a while if the timestamp is marked a certain amount of time back (the wheel has not moved since), and if so, you know the trackwheel has stopped.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I ended up doing. Thanks for your reply